# How can I customize the bottom tab bar of UITabBarController to this exact mockup?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to customise the bottom bar of the UITabBarController to like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this web page would be of some value to you:

[Recreating the raised Center Tab Bar Button...](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/http://)

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy on iOS 5xx and above. You need to look at the UIAppearance proxy methods which allow skinning of Apple default UIKit elements.

UITabBar has

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImage *backgroundImage
```

UITabBarItem has

```
- (void)setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:
- (void)setTitlePositionAdjustment:
```

Comment: and i can replace the center button with a picture? that is of the camera?